# ES6 import doesnt work in jest even after babel config, throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs

Added the dependencies

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
"babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"jest": "^23.4.2",
"jest-cli": "^23.4.2",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1"
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
 {
 "presets": ["env"]
 }
```

Still, when running the test SyntaxError: Unexpected token export is generated

Comment: Please include the full error message with stack trace. The message itself is not enough information.

Comment: Here is the stack trace,

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

export { dom };
^^^^^^
    
By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Comment: Please include that in the question, rather than as a comment. Also, that's still not including the stack trace, that is just the error message. Usually the trace is all the lines after the message, which reference line numbers and file names.

Answer (score 0):

What is the location of the file that has the `export { dom };`?

That `env` preset should transpile the `export` syntax unless that file is located inside your `node_modules` like the error message is hinting at.

If it is inside of the `node_modules` then you will need to adjust your `jest.config` file accordingly:

`{
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(name-of-module-that-is-exporting-dom)/)"
    ]
  }
}`

Additional information can be found here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string